# BSC Scan no detect contract deployed

Tags: bscscan

I did a deploy and the contract is not detected as a contract, in the hash it shows the tokens sent to the owner ams when I go to see the contract there is no contract tab, as if it were a wallet

i deployed on remix, and i try use one contract created for deploy other contracts.  i send one of contracts i deployed :
https://bscscan.com/token/0xaa3a88c65f00cbfb3922e930491b1f3ae29286d5

i deployed on tesnet and in testnet ok, the contract appear normally using the contract